# Align button at the bottom of div using CSS

Tags: css, button, alignment

I want to align my button at the bottom right corner of my div. How can I do that?

[image]

Current css of div:

```
    float: right;
    width: 83%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height:625px;
    overflow:auto;
```

Answer (score 293, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute;` to absolutely position an element within a parent div. 
When using `position:absolute;` the element will be positioned absolutely from the first positioned parent div, if it can't find one it will position absolutely from the window so you will need to make sure the content div is positioned.

To make the content div positioned, all `position` values that aren't static will work, but `relative` is the easiest since it doesn't change the divs positioning by itself.

So add `position:relative;` to the content div, remove the float from the button and add the following css to the button:

```
position: absolute;
right:    0;
bottom:   0;
```

Comment: It not working cause I also have a footer at the bottom. So this places my button at the bottom-right corner of page not the div.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Did you also apply `position: relative` to the element that's containing your form+button?

Comment: @Harry Joy: Then it should be relative to that `div`, not the page. If the footer is also contained in this `div`, maybe they just appear to be the same thing. If you know the height of your footer, on the button you can use `bottom: HEIGHT_OF_FOOTERpx`.

Comment: @thirtydot: the footer is not inside div.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Then there's too much confusion here. You should post your HTML/CSS as a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @thirtydot: Got it working. Thnx. missplaced the position:relative. Added it in wrong div.

Comment: Kokos answer was right on the spot. Many people have mentioned the position:absolute; on other posts, but no one I have seen mentioned the importance of the parent element position: relative; thank you, that has been bothering me for months!

Comment: Really I just have to make a comment and really point out how happy I am to have found this solution. This has been bugging me for years!

Comment: Is there any reason why this might not work in a Bootstrap modal? I added style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;" to the button and style="position:relative;" to the div containing the button yet the button appears to be floating to the top ... had to make bottom like a -57 to get it close

Answer (score 68):

CSS3 flexbox can also be used to align button at the bottom of parent element.

**Required HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-holder">
    <button type="button">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
.container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.container .btn-holder {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Output Image]

**Useful Resources:**

- [Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160526/#box-model)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
  font: 14px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container .btn-holder {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
.container .btn-holder button {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... Lorem ip sum dolor sit amet... </p>
  <div class="btn-holder">
    <button type="button">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

Parent container has to have this:

```
position: relative;
```

Button itself has to have this:

```
position: relative;
bottom: 20px;
right: 20px;
```

or whatever you like

Comment: Note that this answer is incorrect. With `position:relative` the button will be moved from its original position instead of based on the parent.

Comment: You need to use `position: absolute` in order for it from the bottom-right.

Comment: The parent component must have the relative tag and button should have an absolute tag. Thanks @CaptainBli.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this using position fixed:

```
.button-corner {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
position: sticky;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score -28):

Goes to the right and can be used the same way for the left

```
.yourComponent
{
   float: right;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This only aligns your button to the right. Not the bottom right.

Comment: float: right will align your button to the right but bottom property will not work, bottom only works with position other than static