# Center Submit button

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to but my button in center but not working it's take the left

I'm trying to add  to html code but not working

This is the html code :

```
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="submit" class="positive" name="save">
        <img src="apply2.png" alt=""/> 
        Save
    </button>
    <a href="" class="regular">
        <img src="textfield_key.png" alt=""/> 
        Change Password
    </a>

    <a href="" class="regular">
        <img src="downloads.png" alt=""/> 
        Downloads
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="negative">
        <img src="cross.png" alt=""/>
        Cancel
    </a>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

This is the CSS Code:

```
.buttons a, .buttons button{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 7px 0 0;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-left:1px solid #eee;

    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:130%;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#565656;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:5px 10px 6px 7px; /* Links */
}
.buttons button{
    width:auto;
    overflow:visible;
    padding:4px 10px 3px 7px; /* IE6 */
}
.buttons button[type]{
    padding:5px 10px 5px 7px; /* Firefox */
    line-height:17px; /* Safari */
}
*:first-child+html button[type]{
    padding:4px 10px 3px 7px; /* IE7 */
}
.buttons button img, .buttons a img{
    margin:0 3px -3px 0 !important;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}

button:hover, .buttons a:hover{
    background-color:#dff4ff;
    border:1px solid #c2e1ef;
    color:#336699;
}
.buttons a:active{
    background-color:#6299c5;
    border:1px solid #6299c5;
    color:#fff;
}

button.positive, .buttons a.positive{
    color:#529214;
}
.buttons a.positive:hover, button.positive:hover{
    background-color:#E6EFC2;
    border:1px solid #C6D880;
    color:#529214;
}
.buttons a.positive:active{
    background-color:#529214;
    border:1px solid #529214;
    color:#fff;
}

.buttons a.negative, button.negative{
    color:#d12f19;
}
.buttons a.negative:hover, button.negative:hover{
    background:#fbe3e4;
    border:1px solid #fbc2c4;
    color:#d12f19;
}
.buttons a.negative:active{
    background-color:#d12f19;
    border:1px solid #d12f19;
    color:#fff;
}

button.regular, .buttons a.regular{
    color:#336699;
}
.buttons a.regular:hover, button.regular:hover{
    background-color:#dff4ff;
    border:1px solid #c2e1ef;
    color:#336699;
}
.buttons a.regular:active{
    background-color:#6299c5;
    border:1px solid #6299c5;
    color:#fff;
}
```

How to align the submit button vertically in center?

Comment: you want your button to be at the center of the page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button at the center and bottom of div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162560/button-at-the-center-and-bottom-of-div)

Comment: @zan yes in the center of page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float` from tag `button` and `a` and add `text-align` to class `buttons`

Try this demo:

```css
.buttons a,

.buttons button {

  display: inline-block;

  margin: 0 7px 0 0;

  background-color: #f5f5f5;

  border: 1px solid #dedede;

  border-top: 1px solid #eee;

  border-left: 1px solid #eee;

  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;

  font-size: 12px;

  line-height: 130%;

  text-decoration: none;

  font-weight: bold;

  color: #565656;

  cursor: pointer;

  padding: 5px 10px 6px 7px;

  /* Links */

}

.buttons button {

  width: auto;

  overflow: visible;

  padding: 4px 10px 3px 7px;

  /* IE6 */

}

.buttons button[type] {

  padding: 5px 10px 5px 7px;

  /* Firefox */

  line-height: 17px;

  /* Safari */

}

*:first-child+html button[type] {

  padding: 4px 10px 3px 7px;

  /* IE7 */

}

.buttons button img,

.buttons a img {

  margin: 0 3px -3px 0 !important;

  padding: 0;

  border: none;

  width: 16px;

  height: 16px;

}

button:hover,

.buttons a:hover {

  background-color: #dff4ff;

  border: 1px solid #c2e1ef;

  color: #336699;

}

.buttons a:active {

  background-color: #6299c5;

  border: 1px solid #6299c5;

  color: #fff;

}

button.positive,

.buttons a.positive {

  color: #529214;

}

.buttons a.positive:hover,

button.positive:hover {

  background-color: #E6EFC2;

  border: 1px solid #C6D880;

  color: #529214;

}

.buttons a.positive:active {

  background-color: #529214;

  border: 1px solid #529214;

  color: #fff;

}

.buttons a.negative,

button.negative {

  color: #d12f19;

}

.buttons a.negative:hover,

button.negative:hover {

  background: #fbe3e4;

  border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;

  color: #d12f19;

}

.buttons a.negative:active {

  background-color: #d12f19;

  border: 1px solid #d12f19;

  color: #fff;

}

button.regular,

.buttons a.regular {

  color: #336699;

}

.buttons a.regular:hover,

button.regular:hover {

  background-color: #dff4ff;

  border: 1px solid #c2e1ef;

  color: #336699;

}

.buttons a.regular:active {

  background-color: #6299c5;

  border: 1px solid #6299c5;

  color: #fff;

}

.buttons {

  text-align: center;/*added this line*/

}
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button type="submit" class="positive" name="save">
        <img src="apply2.png" alt="" />Save
      </button>
      <a href="" class="regular">
        <img src="textfield_key.png" alt="" />Change Password
      </a>

      <a href="" class="regular">
        <img src="downloads.png" alt="" />Downloads
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="negative">
        <img src="cross.png" alt="" />Cancel
      </a>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You should explain what you did, not just dump code.

Answer (score 1):

just remove `float:left` and include `display:inline-block` in the below class `.buttons a, .buttons button` and include the below css to get this fixed..

**CSS**

```
.buttons{
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/u74e0mjh/)

Answer (score 0):

To center all your buttons add this to your css.

```
.buttons{
width:80%; /* change width as required */
margin:0 auto
}
```