# Why does the css positioning not work as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Regarding to the positioning section of [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817233/align-button-at-the-bottom-of-div-using-css) SO question, it should be possible to align a div element on bottom by applying the following rules:

- container element's style must be `position: relative;`
- target element's style must be `position: absolute; bottom: 10px` (to be aligned 10 px over the container's bottom).

Please find example code in the following [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/N713fT8wxO).

`.container-btn` is the green box that should be placed on buttom, but instead it is placed 10px above the container element. However the settings `top/left/right: 10px` work as expected.

Could anybody explain that behavior? I am just learning CSS and want understand why it behaves that way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `container-btn` is actually 10px from the bottom of it's parent, `col-md-4`, it just happens that the parent doesn't have any height. Giving that column a height like the other, for example, `.col-md-4 { height: 500px; }` you will see the green box move down as you'd expect.

Comment: That explains it, thanks :). Do you see a simple way to solve it?