# How to align element to bottom in a Bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I need to align a box to the **left bottom** of the bootstrap column. Thank you for help.

[image: How I need it]

The problem is that the column has no defined height.

Comment: parent in relative, and box in absokute and left:0 and bottom:0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align button at the bottom of div using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817233/align-button-at-the-bottom-of-div-using-css)

Comment: post your code mate. so we can help you. :)

Comment: The problem is that the .col-6-md has no defined height... okay, I'll post

Comment: You will need to make height of both columns same. And then place button with position absolute. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height) is another post that will be helpful for you.

Comment: position:absolute, left:0, bottom:0 should do the trick. But you need to check before asking, this is fairly simple and probably a duplicate question

Comment: I know that, but it works only if you have the height defined. Not a bootstrap column stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.bottomdiv {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="parent">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
             <div class="bottomdiv">
             </div>             
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer. See [answer].

Answer (score 17):

You can make the column a flexbox and align the element to the end.

```css
.row {
  background: red;
}

.col-6-md {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.bottom {
  background: green;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6-md">
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

in Bootstrap 4, you can use `mt-auto` on the column itself to align an item to the bottom. It should already be aligned to the left by default

Comment: Works in Bootstrap 5 as well, thanks! BR

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4

For all the columns in the entire row use `align-items-end` class on the **row**

For a single column us `align-self-end` on the **col**

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the absolute CSS functionality

```css
.bottom {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

then check the position, alter it to suite you

Answer (score 0):

On Bootstrap 5 you can use the class align-items-bottom:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

So it was pretty cool:

```
.bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0.99rem;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

If you don't want to play with css you can just set:

`class="mb-0"`

It will set margin bottom to zero and should drop your content to the bottom of whatever cell it's in
You can align it in other directions similar way: mb, mt, mr, ml