# How to put the cancel button on the bottom right?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using this code for the "cancel" button. 
How do i make the cancel button to be on the bottom right on the screen.

```
    <button class = "btn btn-secondary margin-r-10" (click)="close()">
    Cancel
    </button>
```

Comment: share your code what you tried before

Comment: check my answer in below if you satisfy then mark this answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this [css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5817282/4964569) to button

```
button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom:  10px;
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rqnqtu

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap,(which I am assuming you are), Please try the following code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Button to the right</title>
      <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<button class = "btn btn-secondary float-right my-2" (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any resolution,

add more class in button this is the class `rightbottom`

and use the css

```
.rightbottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 15%;
}
```

```css
.rightbottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-secondary margin-r-10 rightbottom" (click)="close()">
  Cancel
</button>
```