# CSS Issue with a button placement in a container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am currently making a practise eCommerce website and I have encountered a problem with my styling, I can't figure out how to attach the button to the very bottom of the product container so that other items don't overstretch.
I would ideally like the containers to stretch and balance out the content to the length of the longest item.

[image]

CSS:

```html
.card-container {
    max-width: 80%;
    width:  80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 500px;
}

.product-name {
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

.image-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 250px;
}

.description {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.item-info {
    line-height: 200%;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.card img {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.price {
    font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

JSX:

```html
import './Home.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import fetchItems from '../../utils/fetchItems';

export const Home = () => {
    const [ products, setProducts ]= useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const response = await fetchItems('/products');
            setProducts(response);
        })()
    }, []);    

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to Sahara</h1>
            <div className='card-container'>
                {products.map(product => {
                    return(
                            <div className="card">
                                <img src={product.image} alt='product' />
                                <div className='item-info'>
                                    <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} className='link'><h4 className='product-name'>{product.name}</h4></Link>
                                    <p className='seller'>{product.seller}</p>
                                    <p className='price'>${product.price}</p>
                                    <Link to='/cart'><button>Add to Cart</button></Link>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                    )
                })}  
            </div> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add  `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on `.card`, `margin-top: auto` on `.card button`, wrap the image in a div, you have what want, the button always at the bottom:

[image]

```
import fetchItems from "../../utils/fetchItems";

export const Home = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetchItems("/products");
      setProducts(response);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Sahara</h1>
      <div className="card-container">
        {products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <div className="card">
              <div className="item-img">
                <img src={product.image} alt="product" />
              </div>
              <div className="item-info">
                <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} className="link">
                  <h4 className="product-name">{product.name}</h4>
                </Link>
                <p className="seller">{product.seller}</p>
                <p className="price">${product.price}</p>
              </div>
              <Link to="/cart">
                <button>Add to Cart</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
.card-container {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}

.product-name {
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.image-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 250px;
}

.description {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item-info {
  line-height: 200%;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card img {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.price {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be to have the the `.card` `position: relative;` and the `.card button` be set to `position: absolute;`  Something similar to the below:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue

Comment: I'm glad it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: absolute;` to align the button to the bottom. Add these values to the stylesheet:

```
.card {
    position: relative;
}

.card button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817233/align-button-at-the-bottom-of-div-using-css) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```html
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).